# swift: print string instead of IndexOf an array

Tags: arrays, string, int, indexof

My first array is for English words and my second array contains Spanish words. When the user enters a word in English from array1 the output will be the IndexOf array2. Instead of displaying the IndexOf array2 "1" how can I print the String in array 2.For example, I enter the word "cat" in the text field and click on "translate button" it will print out "0" index of array2. How can I print the word  "gato" instead of 0?

```
var array1: [String]  = ["cat", "dog", "lion"]
var array2: [String]  = ["gato", "perro", "lion"]

for transIndex in array1.indices {
        if array1[transIndex] == emptyString!.lowercaseString {

            translatedWord.text = "\(transIndex)"

            //print("transIndex is \(array1)")
            return   

        }     
    }
```

Comment: Change to `translatedWord.text = "\(array2[transIndex])"`

Comment: Great! that worked many thanks

Comment: Hey, if you have time would you mind checking out my recent post. Still a bit stuck on this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35800592/remove-index-from-array-with-uiimage